# Eclipse, How to keep or memorize selection between operations

Tags: eclipse, replace, comments, block, selection

I am macro'ing with Eclipse 4.3.2 Kepler (http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/ if anyone is interested) and I need to apply successively a Find&Replace then a Add block comment to a selection of code.

My problem is that applying any of those two loses/alter the selection I did manually, preventing  the second operation to perform correctly.

I tried using Restore last selection but this only work if you previously used an Expand selection feature.

Would you know of any mean to keep the selection or "save" it to apply the second op to the same code ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT: edited my version of Eclispe

Comment: which eclipse version are you using?

Comment: Oops, forgot the version. Thanks for pointing it out. Edited my post